# Usar una función que modifica el state como parámetro en React

Tags: reactjs

Necesito enlazar el estado de 2 controles (un navbar y un mapa) de forma que cuando se haga click en una opción del navbar se cargue una ruta en el mapa.

Como estoy usando componentes funcionales para los controles, no puedo usar `this` ni `.bind`.

Lo que estoy haciendo es meter en el state una función que modifica el propio `state`. Luego dicho state es pasado como props a ambos controles.

Mi index.ts tiene esta pinta:

```
 this.state: { 
    rutas: {geojson},
    loaded: false,
    load: () => this.state.loaded = true
 }
 ...
 ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(mapa, this.state), this.containerMap);
 ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(navbar, this.state), this.containerNavBar);
```

Mi control navbar.tsx

```
const showRutas = () => {
    props.load()
}
```

Y mi control map.tsx

```
if (props.loaded = true) {
    show = geojson(props)
}
```

Estoy seguro que showRutas está lanzado correctamente la función load() y que esta cambia el state.loaded a true, lo que no consigo es que tras la actualización se lance el updateView, que es lo que re-renderizaría el control del mapa cargando la ruta.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal en esa función load que paso como parámetro?

Comment: ¿`updateView`? React usa la función `render`. ¿Tu mapa utiliza otra cosa para cargar contenido nuevamente? Podrías intentar hacer algo muy simple que es que si ya se cargaron los datos, tras `show = geojson(props)`, hagas un `this.setState({})` para forzar el `render` otra vez.

Comment: Otra pregunta que tengo es ¿por qué usas `ReactDom.render` en lugar de usar un componente que englobe todo lo que necesitas? Mi recomendación personal, fuera de la solución que propongo en el comentario anterior es que crees un componente `Padre`, que englobe el mapa y el nabab. Dicho componente padre tiene el estado global. En los props, pasas una función escrita en el componente `Padre`, en el que actualices loaded, de esa forma, se ejecutaría el render de ambos componentes al actualizar el state del padre.

Comment: Por cierto, creo que tu actualización del `state` esta mal y ese es el problema, en lugar de ser `load: () => this.state.loaded = true` debes forzosamente usar `load: () => this.setState({loaded: true})`. Si actualizas el estado de forma directa no va a pasar nada.

Comment: El tema es que setState no me aparece como una función disponible para el componente. No estoy usando React a secas, sino que se trata de un custom control de PowerApps, que tiene un ciclo de vida un poco diferente.

Comment: Uso ReactDOM.render, porque necesito poder renderizar diferentes controles según las circunstancias. De este modo map.tsx y navbar.tsx son componentes funcionales cargados aparte e index.ts es el componente principal donde se renderizan todos los demás.

Comment: Si intentaste usar `setState` aunque no aparezca?

Comment: Sí claro, pero ni siquiera transpila con un setState por el medio (uso React con TypeScript).